# How to add another model in ListView that has forign key of the main model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Sorry for my bad english

I'm making a dashboard website
I have 2 models the second one has foreign key of the first one

example of json

model1:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: name1,
   location: location1
}
```

model2:

```
{
   id: 1,
   model1_id: 1,
   photo: "http://url/media/pictures/myphoto478998691182.jpg",
   ...
}
```

So there supposed to be more of model2 to each model1 instance

In my views I have a ListView of model1
I want to add to its context the last photo of model2 referring to each model1 id

If I have 2 instances of model1 each has 5 instances of model2 I want to filter model2 by id and get the last photo for each instance of model1

Sp how to fix this code:

```
class Model1List(CustomLoginRequired, ListView):
model = Model1
paginate_by = 100

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    photo_list = Model2.objects.filter(model1_id = self.kwargs.get('id'))
    photo = list(photo_list.values_list('photo', flat=True))[-1]
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['now'] = timezone.now()
    context['photo'] = photo

    return context
```

To be able to use it in the html template somehow like this

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="branches-list-unit" id="{{ object.slug }}">
            <h5 class="branch-list-unit__name">{{ object.name }}</h5>
            <img class="branch-list-unit__img" src="{{ object.photo }}" 
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context name in the `get_context_data` is called `photo`. You should loop through the context object named `photo`

You are referring to the wrong name in your html template:

```
{% for object in photo %}
    <div class="branches-list-unit" id="{{ object.slug }}">
            <h5 class="branch-list-unit__name">{{ object.name }}</h5>
            <img class="branch-list-unit__img" src="{{ object.photo }}" 
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how to do I filter the model2 objects by the id of model1 on each iteration?

```{% for object in object_list %}```

first object will have an id I want to filter model2 by that id and then pick the last photo after filtering

Comment: this line 

```photo_list = Model2.objects.filter(model1_id = self.kwargs.get('id'))```

it works like this in DetailView, how do I do it in ListView ?

Comment: are your models connected by the foreign key?

Comment: Yes model2 has foreign key of model1